# Send JUnit HTML report to Slack using Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, hyperlink, jenkins-plugins, slack

I am trying to send JUnit HTML report to Slack channel using Jenkins.
I used 'Slack Notifications' step in Jenkins.
Add HTML report link to Custom Message.

```
file://192.168.185.54/c$/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/workspace/ExternalBookingProvider/Results/HTML/ConnectEnterpriseConnector.html
```

This link successfully send to Slack Channel.
The problem is only users which have access to this server can able to view this Report. I want this should be access by any user who has this link.

How can i do this.
Should i use powershell script to upload it to Online Drive and provide that link?

Comment: This is neither a JUnit, nor Jenkins, nor PowerShell, nor Slack problem. You need to put the report on a webserver that the intended users can actually access and send *that* URL.

Comment: Yes you are right. My intend is to target more people related to the technologies i am using, who may faced the same situation in the past.